# Java copy two hash map

Tags: java

I have a class containing Map whose key is string and value is object of another class.

```
          Class Employee {
               String name;
          }

          Class Company {
              Map<String, Employee> m =new HashMap<String, Employee>();
          }
```

I have two Company objects obj1 and obj2, where I want to copy the map from one object to another object.

If I do any of the below things,

```
         obj1 = obj2  or    
         obj1.setM(obj2.getM())   // assume we have setters and getters
```

now if I manipulate obj1's map, making the any of the value to point to different object of Employee for same Company object that obj2 has, where obj2's map is also getting affected.

Is there any way (other than copying key and value to new map and assigning it to object), where we can copy the map contents to another object's map such that manipulating one map doesnot affect other map. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: Look up "deep copying", which is what it seems like you must do, rather than the "shallow" copying that you are currently doing.

Comment: Yup, you need to clone every Employee object instance in hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
obj1 = HashMap<Employee, Company> obj2.clone();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to copy the *map*, you can use

```
new HashMap<String, Employee>(mapToCopy);
```

If you need to modify the employees, you need to copy those objects directly.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but when you're assigning `Employee` to each `Map` you are assigning the *Object Reference*. For each insertion to the `Map` if you want to have a unique item you'll need to execute some form of `clone()` method on the objects.

For instance, the `getM()` function should probably return a form of this...

```
public Employee getM() {
  return new Employee(name,id,....) //constructor to set identical attributes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had read this article on [Deep Copy And Shallow Copy](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/deepcopy_and_shallowcopy.php) sometime ago and bookmarked it. It does well in helping you understand deep copy (clone and serialization variant ) & shallow copy mechanisms. The limitations and issues regarding each copying mechanism.